# How can i create a codeigniter 3 controller that function like a regular php class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to know how can i do a controller like this class in order to call them from view, i want to do it with a controller not a library. if is possible please help.

`

```
<?php
require_once('database.php');
require_once('employees.php');
require_once('photograph.php');

class employees {
    
protected static $table_name = "employees"; 
protected static $db_fields = array('idemployee', 'employeenumber', 'name', 'lastname', 'sex', 'phone', 'email');
    
public $idemployee;
public $employeenumber; 
public $name; 
public $lastname;
public $sex; 
public $phone;
public $email;
    
    
  public function full_name() {
    if(isset($this->name) && isset($this->lastname)) {
      return $this->name . " " . $this->lastname;
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }
  
       public function employee_detail_card() {
      $foto = $this->photo();
      return 
    "<div class='card' style='width:100%;'>
     <img class='card-img-top' src='../../public/images_up/$foto' alt='Card image' width='50%'>
    <div class='card-header'>"
        . $this->botonesFotoPerfil() .
    "</div>
    <div class='card-header card bg-info text-white'>
        Numero ibo: " . $this->employeenumber . "
    </div>
    <div class='card-body'>
    <table class='table table-striped'> 
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Telefono: </strong>" . $this->phone . "</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>E-mail: </strong>" . $this->email . "</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>";
  }


    public function list_employees() {
      return "<tr>" . 
                "<td>" . $this->employeenumber . "</td>" .
                "<td>" . $this->full_name() . "</td>" .
                "<td align='right'>" . $this->phone . "</td> " .
                "<td align='right'>" . $this->email . "</td> ";

    }
}

?>
```

`

i did had a result but with a library, however honestly i understand it is better practice to do it on a controller.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the loader class, first you create your custom class place it under application/library and then load it with the loader class
`$this->load->library('yourclassname');` its very detailed in the documentary which you can find here

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html

but if you want to avoid that for some reason, nothing stops you from doing a simple include/require